# Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC

Tags: mysql, perl

I have installed latest version of Perl from ActiveState version 5.18.2.1802 successfully. I am using Mysql database at back end in windows 8 environment. Wrote down the following code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI;
use DBI;

    $cgiObj = CGI->new;
    print $cgiObj->header('text/html');

    $params = 'DBI:mysql:world:localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = 'XXXXXX!';

    $conn = DBI->connect($params, $user, $pass);
    $sql='select * from city';
    $query =$conn->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute;

    while(@row=$query->fetchrow_array)
    {
        print "ID: $row[0], Name: $row[1]<br>\n";
    }
```

Please some one give me guidence

Comment: Have you installed `DBI` and the related mysql driver?

Comment: You stopped reading the error message too soon. It continued with *you may need to install the DBD::mysql module*. Do you have any reason to believe that the problem is something else?

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you haven't installed DBD::mysql.  But that assumes you have mistyped the error message (it would be "Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm", not "Can't locate DBD/Mysql.pm").

You also aren't setting the DSN as documented; it should be in one of these forms:

```
$dsn = "DBI:mysql:$database";
$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname";
$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$database;host=$hostname;port=$port";
```

Also, you will save yourself a lot of headaches in the future if you always say:

```
use 5.018;
use warnings;
```

in your scripts and properly declare your variables.  (Optionally use a lower minimum version number, but if you specify a version less than 5.012, you will need to also `use strict;` since that won't be done for you.)